# Computing probability in normal distribution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a problem that says

> Let $X \sim N(2, 9).$
>
> Compute $P(1 \le X < 7)$.

I subtracted both sides by $2$ and divided both sides by $9$ to get

\begin{align} F(5/9) - F(-1/9)
    &=F(.555) - F(-.111)\\ &=
    .7088 - .4562 \\&= .2526 \end{align}

but the answer says $0.5818$.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

It looks like this is exactly how my example played out in my book. I'm not sure where to find a better solution because it was such a close example. the only difference is there were $2 \le$ signs in the inequality instead of $1$ like in here.

Comment: $9$ is the variance so you should be dividing by the standard deviation which is $3$ not $9$

Comment: oops.... thanks

Comment: Some sources give the normal as $N(\mu,\sigma)$, while others give it as $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  Be sure to check the convention being used by your source.